# loop using apply templates in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to loop through a xml which has 20 elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
  <products>one</products>
  <products>two</products>
  <products>three</products>
  <products>four</products>
  <products>five</products>
  <products>six</products>
  <products>seven</products>
  <products>eight</products>
  ...
</container>
```

I'm trying to loop through the elements by inserting a line break after every 4 elements

Output required is:

```
one two three four
five six seven eight
...
```

Can you give some pointers on the how to achieve this 
can this be done using apply templates?

Comment: Please edit the question to show an example of the XML you're starting from and whatever XSLT you've tried so far.  What exactly is the output you're after (if you're looking for HTML or XML output then we need to see the actual HTML/XML _source_, not just how it would look when rendered by a browser)?

Comment: @kjhughes Please don't edit OP's code; you don't know what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a text output, try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="container/products">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 4">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It still gives the output in a straight line  as
 one two three four five six seven eight nine

Answer (score 1):

## Solution Using Pure Pattern Matching

You can achieve your desired results more naturally in XSLT using *pattern matching* without looping.

**This XSLT transform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products[position() mod 4 = 0]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
  <products>one</products>
  <products>two</products>
  <products>three</products>
  <products>four</products>
  <products>five</products>
  <products>six</products>
  <products>seven</products>
  <products>eight</products>
</container>
```

**Will produce the desired output:**

```
one two three four
five six seven eight
```

**Using *pattern matching* rather than looping.**

Comment: still gives in a straight line. It doesent break after4
one two three four five six seven eight nine

Comment: @user2628187, this code is complete, self-contained, and works exactly as shown.  I suggest that you first confirm its operation (http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyM) apart from your context and then re-examine how you're adapting it.